# Communication between a child process and a parent process

Tags: c, linux

I'm developing a program in c, where child process receives a system command given by user and passes it to its parent process and parent process execute that command. Can anyone help me with the code or any example code. Any form of help is highly appreciable.

Comment: What part of your program more specifically is it you have problems with? Creation of the child process? Communication between the processes? Something else? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then go to your favorite search site and try searching for answers to each of your problems, there are thousands of examples all over the Internet about each of these subjects.

Comment: `man fork pipe exec`

Answer (score 1):

I think before posting you should look to previous answers to questions of this kind. 
Anyway there are several ways in which two different processes can talk. I suggest you to look at pipes and in general to the interprocess communication technologies.
Remember that stackoverflow is a site where after you have tried and studied the problem you can ask for help. I think you have skipped the first step.

Answer (score 0):

If it is 2 distinct process (i.e. fork()), you can share data through a shared memory : http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html
Please read this document that will explain you the way to do so